# SPC - Control Charts by Group in R

Tags: r, charts, qcc, spc

I want to create a statistical process control chart for each Name in this dataframe and extract the rows that are out of control for each individual Name.

Below is the dataframe:

```
DATE <- as.Date(c('2016-06-18', '2016-06-19', '2016-06-20', 
              '2016-06-21', '2016-06-22', '2016-06-23', 
              '2016-06-24', '2016-06-25', '2016-06-26', 
              '2016-06-27', '2016-06-28', '2016-06-29', 
              '2016-06-30', '2016-06-18', '2016-06-19', 
              '2016-06-20', '2016-06-21', '2016-06-22', 
              '2016-06-23', '2016-06-24', '2016-06-25', 
              '2016-06-26', '2016-06-27', '2016-06-28', 
              '2016-06-29', '2016-06-30', '2016-06-18',
              '2016-06-19', '2016-06-20', '2016-06-21',
              '2016-06-22', '2016-06-23', '2016-06-24',
              '2016-06-25', '2016-06-26', '2016-06-27',
              '2016-06-28', '2016-06-29', '2016-06-30'))

Name <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
          'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
          'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')

Revenue <- c(0.08, 0.03, 0.09, 2, 0.09, 0.29, 0.56, 0.23, 0.12, 0.76, 0.23, 0.45,0.32,
             0.10, 0.14, 0.80, 0.3, 0.12, 0.75, 0.20, 0.09, 0.22, 0.11, 4, 0.30, 0.45,
             0.19, 0.23, 0.56, 0.77, 0.9, 9, 0.38, 0.11, 0.98, 0.87, 0.09, 0.20, 0.65)
df<-data.frame(DATE, Name, Revenue)

dput(df)
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(16970, 16971, 16972, 16973, 
16974, 16975, 16976, 16977, 16978, 16979, 16980, 16981, 16982, 
16970, 16971, 16972, 16973, 16974, 16975, 16976, 16977, 16978, 
16979, 16980, 16981, 16982, 16970, 16971, 16972, 16973, 16974, 
16975, 16976, 16977, 16978, 16979, 16980, 16981, 16982), class = "Date"), 
Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Revenue = c(0.08, 0.03, 0.09, 
2, 0.09, 0.29, 0.56, 0.23, 0.12, 0.76, 0.23, 0.45, 0.32, 
0.1, 0.14, 0.8, 0.3, 0.12, 0.75, 0.2, 0.09, 0.22, 0.11, 4, 
0.3, 0.45, 0.19, 0.23, 0.56, 0.77, 0.9, 9, 0.38, 0.11, 0.98, 
0.87, 0.09, 0.2, 0.65)), .Names = c("DATE", "Name", "Revenue"), 
row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = "data.frame")

df

> df
         DATE Name Revenue
1  2016-06-18    A    0.08
2  2016-06-19    A    0.03
3  2016-06-20    A    0.09
4  2016-06-21    A    2.00
5  2016-06-22    A    0.09
6  2016-06-23    A    0.29
7  2016-06-24    A    0.56
8  2016-06-25    A    0.23
9  2016-06-26    A    0.12
10 2016-06-27    A    0.76
11 2016-06-28    A    0.23
12 2016-06-29    A    0.45
13 2016-06-30    A    0.32
14 2016-06-18    B    0.10
15 2016-06-19    B    0.14
16 2016-06-20    B    0.80
17 2016-06-21    B    0.30
18 2016-06-22    B    0.12
19 2016-06-23    B    0.75
20 2016-06-24    B    0.20
21 2016-06-25    B    0.09
22 2016-06-26    B    0.22
23 2016-06-27    B    0.11
24 2016-06-28    B    4.00
25 2016-06-29    B    0.30
26 2016-06-30    B    0.45
27 2016-06-18    C    0.19
28 2016-06-19    C    0.23
29 2016-06-20    C    0.56
30 2016-06-21    C    0.77
31 2016-06-22    C    0.90
32 2016-06-23    C    9.00
33 2016-06-24    C    0.38
34 2016-06-25    C    0.11
35 2016-06-26    C    0.98
36 2016-06-27    C    0.87
37 2016-06-28    C    0.09
38 2016-06-29    C    0.20
39 2016-06-30    C    0.65
```

I want to write a script that will create a **control chart** using the `qcc` package for each **Name** and then callout the rows that are **beyond the limits** for the control chart of each name.

So I know how to make a normal individual control chart for each name separately which would be this. Name: "A" for example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(qcc)
target <- c("A")
testing<-filter(df, Name %in% target)
library(qcc)
my.xmr.x <- qcc(testing$Revenue, type = "xbar.one", plot=TRUE)
beyond.limits(my.xmr.x)
```

Result:

[image]

Result is one data point beyond the limits being just for Name **A**:

```
6
```

My goal is to write a script that will extract the rows for all names(not just the row number like 6).

So here is what I want the output to look like in the end:

```
Out_of_Control_Rows_By_Name
         DATE     Name Revenue 
   6  2016-06-21    A    2.00
   11 2016-06-28    B    4.00
   6  2016-06-23    C    9.00
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: In the future it would be preferable to share the data with `dput` so that it can be easily read into R. Especially when you have rownames, as that makes it harder to take data from your question and try to read it in.

Comment: do you still want me to do it or were you able to read it in R the way it is? @Hack-R

Comment: @Hack-R added dput to the dataframe. Hope this makes it easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks much. I was having some trouble finding the time to work on this but I will try to get to it today and your update will also help other people to answer.

Comment: @Hack-R also let me know if you want me to clear anything up in what the actual question is. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I feel bad that you've been so neglected. I've got 10 minutes to work on it right now. If I can't finish I'll try to come back to it this evening.

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks @Hack-R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(pacman) # you don't have to use this; it's my package manager
p_load(dplyr,qcc)

tmp <- df[0,]
for(i in unique(df$Name)){
  testing<-filter(df, Name == i)
  my.xmr.x <- qcc(testing$Revenue, type = "xbar.one", plot=TRUE)
  beyond.limits(my.xmr.x)
  df2 <- df[df$Name == i,]
  tmp <- rbind(tmp,df2[beyond.limits(my.xmr.x),])
}
```

> ```
>          DATE Name Revenue
> 4  2016-06-21    A       2
> 24 2016-06-28    B       4
> 32 2016-06-23    C       9
> ```

Comment: This works great on this dataset but not on my larger one for some reason. An error comes up, any idea what I need to change in the script to remove the error?: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Comment: I think it has to do with missing values because in my actual dataset, I not all of the names occur together on each DATE. So there are a couple Name's for example that do not occur on some dates causing NA's in the plot

Comment: Going one step further with this. I think the issue may be that when it calculates the limits in the chart. Because of the numbers, it is outputting an NA values not allowing the chart to plot/compute limits. So I need to find a way to create this without NA somehow. Sorry for all the comments. Thanks @Hack-R

Comment: Last one, promise haha. So I just did plot=FALSE and it worked for getting the points out of bounds. Thanks again @Hack-R !!

Comment: It probably is because of missing values as you hypothesized (unless you literally have infinite values). You might need to either impute them (`RRF::na.roughfix` or Amelia II, etc, etc) or exclude them. It's hard to say without an example. If you can provide an example I can help with it tonight or tomorrow.